# Failed to establish connection to MySQL database in C++

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I have recently tried to make a connection to my SQL database in C++ using QSqlDatabase. Here is a small part of my code.

```
void guimain::on_pushbutton_clicked(){
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");       
    db.setHostName("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306");    
    db.setDatabaseName("MyDatbase");    
    db.setUserName("username");    
    db.setPassword("password");    
    bool connected = db.open();    
    cout<< connected\n;    
}
```

everytime i run the program it prints connected as 0 meaning it has not connected to the database. I have double checked the correctness of the password, username, database and everything else. What else could be the problem?

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: which OS you have use? linux or window?

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi There is no error, if there was i would have stated it. It just prints connected (bool to check if connection is made) as 0. So i am wondering why wont it connect to my database.

Comment: Perhaps because you are not running a mysql server on port 3306?

Comment: what is your service? `tcp` or `http`?

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi Arch Linux 4.18.14. I have setup MySQL and MariaDB sucessfully already and have access to them via MySQL-Workbench. It is a TCP service

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I am running it on 3306

Comment: How are you running it? Are you sure about the user and password?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Yes i am sure. I have triple checked it already.

Comment: Do you have the connector installed?

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you're suppressing errors?

```
cout<< connected\n;
```

should be

```
cout<< "connected\n";
```

or, if you meant to output the string "connected" if a connection has been made:

```
cout<< connected ? "connected\n" : "failed to connect\n";
```

And putting the former should have resulted in an error being outputted.

Also you put the name as "MyDatbase" which seems like you misspelt "MyDatabase".

*Edit: Not sure why I'm getting downvoted. You told us that you got no errors but I see a clear syntax error, so either you're not being truthful or you're suppressing errors. Suppressing errors is bad practice - avoid it. As for why it actually fails to connect, it seems like you've misspelt the database name, as I said above.*

Comment: connected is a boolean value which is true when connected and false when disconnected from the database.

Comment: \ is not a valid operator for a boolean if I recall correctly. By \n what do you mean?

Comment: I have corrected the cout to be "cout<< connected << endl;" Anyways what i was hoping to find out is why wouldnt the connection to my database be established.

Comment: I'm more interested in the fact that you said you got no errors though... Are you suppressing errors?

Comment: Also "MyDatbase" or "MyDatabase"